# tvOS UITextView - How to edit it

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, tvos

I have an UITextView with `userInteraction = YES` and `selectable = YES` and I can focus it (I have checked focusing with `didUpdateFocusInContext`) but I cannot edit it because the keyboard never appears.

I have also tried to set the delegate method but `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` is never called.

The `editable` property appears not available in code.

Am I missing something? Is the textview editable or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the simulator, make sure you don't have it set to use the hardware keyboard only.

Hardware -> Keyboard -> Try the two toggles

Comment: I have the same problem both using the simulator and the actual device. Anyway, tks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something similar to the `UITextView` to get the keyboard to show:

```
UITextField* postField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
postField.delegate = self;
postField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeTwitter;
[self addSubview:postField];
//Show Keyboard for input
[postField becomeFirstResponder];
```